# Writing IRC Services for UnrealIRCD

Tags: php, irc

Well, I've been searching for material for this one, and failed to find anything. I am familiar with the IRC protocol, and I want to write **IRC Services** for my server (running on **[UnrealIRCD](http://www.unrealircd.com)**)

I prefer PHP, as I am most proficient there. Can anyone point me at some good tutorials or even explain here how to start? (I only need the basic protocol/syntax and server settings, I'll do the actual functions and abilities myself (hopefully :P)).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.phpclasses.org/package/1409-PHP-IRC-client-for-creating-chats-or-bots.html could help you.

Comment: Do services act like a client? @Hikaru-Shindo

Comment: Services are like (U-Line) a server with a special line yes... But you may get some protocol information there ... I would tend to write services in C or use the existing ones (e.x. Anope).

Comment: Yes, but the point is to challenge myself and build it myself. Services are like a server? Does it mean I need to write an IRC server that may link to UnrealIRCD?

Comment: That's right. Services are linked like a server and have a U-Line set which enables them to use some special permissions.

Comment: Okay, so if I somehow join the services' server, will I be able to see users joining channels (I'm  not on) etc, like services can? (ChanServ can op people on channels it's not on), also what kind of special permissions do they get? All of this is material I couldn't find on the internet btw.

Comment: Each server gets messages on clients activities (connect, disconnect, channel joins/parts etc). A U-Line also bypasses every oper restriction, can set mode on all channels and issue server-only/u-line only modes (e.g. the service user mode!). A lot of information can be found at Unreal's reference: http://www.unrealircd.com/files/docs/unreal32docs.html#ulinesblock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A friend of mine me did this one already for InspIRCd. It never was finished, but the basics were working. We simply connected to the IRC server via a Socket-Connection (fsockopen in the first version, socket_create in the second one).

For communication we implemented an interface to InspIRCd with contained the specific lines as stated in the protocol. These methods could then be called by the core.

Comment: You my friend, may just be the "youngest" member I'll ever award with a bounty. I'll take a look when I have more time. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Simply outstanding! How can I contact you if I have questions?

Answer (score 1):

Reading uncompiled C source code of the Anope services got me pointed in the right direction, although it's a bit of a trial and error as to where to look inside it. I can't remember since it was quite a while ago when I tried my own PHP services, but if each client the services connects requires a PING/PONG reply to keep the connection alive, then won't PHP kinda fall down? The threading isn't that great, Linux only as far as I can remember.

Comment: I'll give it a try as well. I'm a bit rusty at C though :P Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:  Good Lord, I didn't realize how old this question was. That being said, someone might use it so...answer below.

I've done this in PHP so I can tell you it can be done (source code not released).

That being said, I'll throw a basic core at you here:

```
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 6);
// Prevent fast reconnects if server down but try to connect every ten seconds.
while ( !socket_connect($socket,ADDRESS,PORT) ) {

    sleep(10);
}
// set non blocking to avoid 'waiting' for data
socket_set_nonblock($socket);
// INTENTIONAL INFINITE LOOP
while(1) { 
    $read = array($socket);
    // check if there's anything to read.
    $num_changed_sockets = @socket_select($read, null, null, 0, 1);
    if ( $num_changed_sockets > '0' ) {
        // process the socket data here
        processSocket(socket_read($socket,10000,PHP_NORMAL_READ));
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you get started!